# Grep multiple strings and output to multiple files

Tags: ubuntu, grep

I found questions here about grepping multiple strings and questions about outputting to multiple files, but I can't seem to find any about doing both at the same time.

I have a 300GB file that I need to do a regex grep on for about 1200 strings. I'm trying to grep the file once so it doesn't have to circle through it 1200 times.

Here's an example of what I'm currently doing 1200 times:

```
grep -hi "^1wh" /system/data/DATAFILE.txt > /system/tables/wh.csv
grep -hi "^1wi" /system/data/DATAFILE.txt > /system/tables/wi.csv
grep -hi "^1wj" /system/data/DATAFILE.txt > /system/tables/wj.csv
grep -hi "^1wk" /system/data/DATAFILE.txt > /system/tables/wk.csv
grep -hi "^1al" /system/data/DATAFILE.txt > /system/tables/al.csv
grep -hi "^1am" /system/data/DATAFILE.txt > /system/tables/am.csv
grep -hi "^1an" /system/data/DATAFILE.txt > /system/tables/an.csv
```

The name of the output file is the same as the string bring searched for - without the number 1 at the front.

Is there any way to grep the file once for multiple strings and output the results of each string to different files, so I don't have to run grep 1200 times?

Comment: Not really with grep ... awk might work for you, though, that depends on whether the matches are clearly defined or rather positional. But the description and the desired output don't match up; the regex suggests there's a `1` in the match, but the filenames don't have it.

Comment: From where do you get those 1200 strings? Add an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with the commenter that this does not seem to be possible with `grep`.

What about something like the following, which iterates over the regular expressions to generate an `awk` program that appends each line of the datafile to its appropriate output file:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p output
rm -f output/*
rm -f pattern.awk

readarray -t patterns < patterns

echo "BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1}" > pattern.awk

for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"; do
    echo "/$pattern/{print \$0 >> \"output/$pattern\"}" >> pattern.awk
done

awk -f pattern.awk data
```

Result:

```
$ cat data
1Abfoo
1whfoo
1wifoo
1wjfoo
43hfoo
1wkfoo
1abfoo


$ cat patterns
^1wh
^1wi
^1wj
^1wk
^1ab

$ ./parse.sh

$ head output/*
==> output/^1ab <==
1Abfoo
1abfoo

==> output/^1wh <==
1whfoo

==> output/^1wi <==
1wifoo

==> output/^1wj <==
1wjfoo

==> output/^1wk <==
1wkfoo
```

Comment: Well this is definitely 100x faster than the way I was using grep, but I'm getting this error: `awk: cannot open "output/^1pi" for output (Too many open files)` after it runs for about a 2 seconds.  Is there a way to increase how many files awk can have open or change something in the code?

Comment: I actually just checked `ulimit -n` and my file limit was set to 1024.  I ran `ulimit -n 2500` and it fixed that problem.  I think the only problem I'm seeing is that your script is case sensitive.  Is there a way to make it case insensitive like my grep was?  For example, `1Ab` should go into `output/^1ab` but right now it doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: @Hemimu Yes, I've updated my answer and sample results, but it requires GNU `awk`. I believe Ubuntu by default uses `mawk`, so you may need to `apt-get install gawk`.